# Calculating bit score: How do you find lambda and K?

Tags: blast, bitscore

To calculate bitscore from score you can use this equation: $S' = (lambda*S - ln(K)) / ln(2)$

If I am trying to manually calculate the bitscore of an HSP of a pairwise blastn alignment, and I know the alignment score, how do I calculate the parameters K and lambda?

Is there a more simple equation for pairwise nucleotide alignments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NCBI BLAST uses tables of pre-computed values for lambda/K for gapped protein and nucleotide comparison and their values depend on the amino acid substitution matrix or the substitution scores + gap penalties.

You can find these tables (from line 589 for blastn) in the file `c++/src/algo/blast/core/blast_stat.c` from the [blast source package](ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/blast/executables/blast+/LATEST/ncbi-blast-2.7.1+-src.tar.gz).